# Verificar se um valor está presente em um array em Ruby

Tags: array, ruby

Como verificar se certo valor está contido em um array em Ruby? Por exemplo, quero saber se `'A'` está presente no vetor `['A','B','C']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o método [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F).

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.include?("b")   #=> true
a.include?("z")   #=> false
```